# Jquery and document.write not playing nice

Tags: jquery, document.write

I have a javascript that needs to be loaded on the "completion" page of an ecommerce site, here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var skulist="",pricelist="",quantitylist="";
for (var i=0; i < OrderDetails.length; i++){
skulist = OrderDetails[i][2]+","+skulist;
pricelist =OrderDetails[i][5]+","+pricelist;
quantitylist =OrderDetails[i][6]+","+quantitylist;
}

skulistLen=skulist.length;

skulist = skulist.slice(0,skulistLen-1);

pricelistLen=pricelist.length;

pricelist = pricelist.slice(0,pricelistLen-1);

quantitylistLen=quantitylist.length;

quantitylist = quantitylist.slice(0,quantitylistLen-1);

document.write("<iframe height='1' width='1' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' src='https://www.emjcd.com/tags/c?containerTagId=49296&ITEM1="+skulist+"&AMT1="+pricelist+"&QTY1="+quantitylist+"&CID=10000171&OID=$(OrderNo)&TYPE=362565438&CURRENCY=USD' name='cj_conversion'></iframe>");


</script>
```

and I need to call it with jquery... (for other reasons) - 
and I am doing so like this:

```
<div id="cj-placeholder"><!--placeholder--></div>
<script>
if($.cookie("so-affiliate") ) {
    $().ready(function() {
    // load external file
    //$('#cj-placeholder').load('/v/js/cj.html', function() {
    //return;
    $.get('/v/js/cj.html')
 .success(function(data) {
     $('#cj-placeholder').html(data);

});
});


}else{
  $('#cj-placeholder').append('.');

}
</script>
```

the problem is, when I do this, I get a blank page with ONLY the contents of cj.html inside (the script) - it is replacing the order finished page instead of appending to it...  by searching here, I learned that if a document.write is called like this AFTER the page is loaded then it'll replace it as it is, problem is.... what do I do?

Comment: Quick question: why are you using `document.write()`? Did you get that from w3schools?

Comment: its just the code I have that works if on the page aside from being called by the jquery... if there'a a different way to get thet iframe loaded WITH the variables from the rest of the javascript! I'm fine with it, I just can't find any other way that works?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `append`

```
$('body').append("<iframe height='1' width='1' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' src='https://www.emjcd.com/tags/c?containerTagId=49296&ITEM1="+skulist+"&AMT1="+pricelist+"&QTY1="+quantitylist+"&CID=10000171&OID=$(OrderNo)&TYPE=362565438&CURRENCY=USD' name='cj_conversion'></iframe>");
```

Comment: when I do that, it doesnt "run" the variables in that iframe that are part of the javascript above where I have document write now.

Comment: @CVP did you replace the document.write line with this one

Comment: I didnt because the document.write is in my javascript, and that is a jquery? can I do that, would it work... I will try it...